# MySql multiple Join with relationship tables

Tags: mysql, sql

i have the query

```
SELECT task.* FROM task
        JOIN client_task ON task.ID=client_task.taskid
        WHERE client_task.clientid = 2
```

I have a client, a task and a project table. The client_task table keeps relations between objects of client and taask table. I have one more table called project_task and i want to check if the selected task is related to a given projectid...

Is this somehow possible or do i need a second query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easy to add another join. And yes, that should work just the same.

```
SELECT 
    task.* 
FROM 
    task
JOIN client_task 
    ON task.ID = client_task.taskid
JOIN project_task
    ON task.ID = project_task.taskid
WHERE 
    client_task.clientid = 2
AND
    project_task.projectid = <given projectid>
```

Comment: this is correct answer for sure and nicely formatted too :)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if i understand your behavier.

Please try this query:

```
select * from project_task  where taskid in (SELECT task.id FROM task
        JOIN client_task ON task.ID=client_task.taskid
        WHERE client_task.clientid = 2)
```